# How can I repair /run/resolvconf/interface missing error?

Tags: package-management, network-manager, dpkg, resolvconf

An upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 15 failed.  Package repair hangs at this point:

```
Setting up resolvconf (1.77ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.77ubuntu1) ...
resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface
either does not exist or is not a directory
dpkg: error processing package resolvconf (--configure)
```

How can I get past this point?

```
sudo apt-get remove resolvconf
```

I want to remove ubuntu-base, which seems not to be a good idea.
I see [this Debian Bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749405).

The problem was probably triggered by a manual attempt on my part to start networking using old-school editing of `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /run/resolvconf/interface` ..also after changing `/etc/resolv.conf` manually you could just do `sudo resolvconf -u` do make `resolvconf` creating it again..`resolvconf` depends on `lsb-base` so removing it won't be a good idea..

Comment: sudo resolvconf -u does not help. /run/resolvconf/ does not exist.

Comment: You can try `sudo mkdir -p /run/resolvconf/interface` and re-running your package repair. If that fails it might be difficult to fix and you may need to remove and re-install a ton of packages and you may have a broken system. See also - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: I ran the repair script, except this time did not first start networking at that boot.  Now it worked.

Comment: @Bryce, which repair script?